# SonarQube ecosystem upgrades (SonarQube and SonarLint)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube5.2, sonarlint

We are using SonarQube 5.1 and want to upgrade to SonarQubee 5.2 or 5.3 due to some issues around issue assign area of SonarQube 5.1
We are also using SonarQube eclipse plugin 3.5.0

I noticed recently that SonarQube eclipse plugin 3.5.0 is not supported with SonarQube 5.2 as per http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse.

Also latest SonarLint release 1.2 cannot connect to remote Sonar Instance to fetch server rules. This feature was available with SonarQube eclipse plugin 3.5.0.
I found on Stackoverflow that SonarLint would support this feature with release 2.0 but there is no planned release date for 2.0
[Getting remote config file for SonarLint if online, using local if offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092359/getting-remote-config-file-for-sonarlint-if-online-using-local-if-offline)

1. My question is why SonarQube ecosystem upgrades are not synchronised? 
   SonarQube eclipse plugin should support latest SonarQube releases until SonarLint is capable to connect to remote Sonar instance to fetch server rules.
2. How anyone who are supposed to take SonarQube upgrades to resolve problems with existing version could execute eclipse analysis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have read, the [SonarQube Eclipse plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarqube) has been deprecated in favor of [SonarLint for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint). One of the main reasons behind this is that SonarLint for Eclipse is designed to be an independant product which lifecycle must be decoupled from SonarQube - in order to ease and speed up innovation on the user experience in the IDE. So by now, SonarQube and SonarLint upgrades are not synchronized by definition.

Still, your question is perfectly valid: why don't we make some last updates on the SQ Eclipse plugin as long as SonarLint is not able to connect to a SonarQube server? The main reason is that we believe so much in SonarLint that we want to focus all our attention and energy on that product, and therefore we want to move fast to be able to have the "connected-to-SonarQube" experience as soon as possible. Our telemetry tells us that most existing users and customers are currently using a SonarQube version that is still usable with the SQ Eclipse plugin, so I feel this is the right decision to work as fast as possible on SonarLint to make sure it can connect to a SonarQube instance in the upcoming months (when the next LTS is released).

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabrice for your response. Would you be able to provide tentative timeline by when SonarLint would be able to connect to SonarQube instance so that it could help us plan our SonarQube upgrade better.

Comment: Current ETA for 5.x LTS is June 2016. So for sure the connected experience in SonarLint will be there at that point of time. Still, with all the work we're currently doing, I feel that we'll have it earlier - by March/April hopefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabrice for the feedback. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following combination works fine 
(SonarLint + SonarScanner + SonarQube + Eclipse):

---

```
SonarLint: 3.5.0.201804241315
sonarScanner: sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227-windows
SonarQube:  6.7.4 (build 38452)
```

---

### sonar-scanner.properties:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.projectKey=JavaProject
sonar.projectName=MyJavaStandaloneProject
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
sonar.sources=D:/eclipse/workspace/MyJavaStandaloneProject
sonar.java.binaries=D:/eclipse/workspace/MyJavaStandaloneProject/target/classes
```

### pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

### Bind Eclipse projects to SonarQube projects:

Select a SonarQube server: **localhost**

 Eclipse Project: MyJavaStandaloneProject

  *SonarQube Project: 'MyJavaProject' on server localhost*

Click: Auto bind selected projects.

"Note: SonarQube Project: 'MyJavaProject' on server localhost

 can be auto configured by clicking Auto bind button."

---

All configurations done.

---

Right click project and **Run As**  Maven build ...

Goal: **sonar:sonar**

---

**[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL**